# Profiling a Linux box to find causes of slowness

Tags: performance, profiling

I use a (Fedora) Linux box for daily work, and generally I boot it every morning, so we are not talking about long running processes and short uptimes.

Lately I noticed that the system got slow, but I am having a hard time identifying the issue: the system might hang for a while, I log in via ssh and, at least in the console, it runs smoothly. I run top/htop and see that no process is taking huge amounts of RAM or CPU, but the GUI is still unresponsive (or extremely lagging).

I would like to get some data and understand what is going on: what tools could I use to diagnose the problem and capture some time series of events? Especially across multiple boots. It is fine to collect up to 1GB of data a day (on disk), but I don't think I can afford more.

Relying on system logs is also a viable option, but I don't know how to "see the big picture" (also, I don't think that logging is providing such a complete picture of the system status).

Comment: If is GUI issues you are having i would suggest looking at /var/logs/messages and see check for errors. 

For performance, there is an application named sar that collect info about cpu, ram, i/o and some other stuff. 

I hope this gives you a good place to start

Comment: I did not know about sar, thank you. I am not sure it is a GUI issue, but I'll keep system log under control.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe PCP (Performance Co-Pilot) is an option? [RHEL 8 documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/monitoring_and_managing_system_status_and_performance/index)

If you are using Fedora **maybe** Wayland is actually a problem?

Comment: Yes, wayland might be a problem. I'll check out PCP, thanks!